# How to convert Object to Json format including dynamic table using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert javascript Object to Json format?

I can create object data when user submit the form and i dont know how to convert submit data like json format?

can you tell me how to do?

here is my sample code..,

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/7mo39ate/)**

Example

```
  "cashpayments": [
{
  "name": something,
  "email": something,
  "password": null
}]                        <<<<< --- LIKE THAT --- >>>>>
```

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {

        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery);

$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeFormJSON();
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: its not work for me sir

Comment: You can try this : https://jsfiddle.net/739up4z5/

Comment: i just want to like                                                             JSON FORMAT:
 {
  "vouchno": 3,
  "reason": null,
  "ledgerno": null,
  "entrytype": null,
  "vouchdt": null,"cashpayments": [
    {
      "acctcode": 41,
      "debit": 10000,
      "credit": null,
      "narr": "",
      "actname": "ACCOUNT1"
    },
    {
      "acctcode": 41,
      "debit": 10000,
      "credit": null,
      "narr": "",
      "actname": "ACCOUNT1"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: What is the issue you are facing in forming that?

Comment: I'm getting two times data. when i click submit button it will come two times

Comment: Updated your fiddle for you.  Since there's no mention of "cashpayments" in the code/html (only the result), I hardcoded it into the answer, so it's not a generic/reusable method, but gives you want you want using your existing code with a `.push`: https://jsfiddle.net/v91od2m0/

Comment: *"I'm getting two times data"* - not in your fiddle or your provided code.  So there's some other code you've got that forcing the submit to click twice - running the handler twice maybe?

Comment: Sir, in this case not work for me, the dropdown datas.. see my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/ke3htsdm/

Comment: @freedomn-m my problem is not getting dynamic table values, when i add multiple rows its not get values..

Comment: *None* of that is in your question which asks how to convert to JSON.  Perhaps ask a new question with your *actual* problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201207/discussion-between-joe-and-freedomn-m).